# Publishing new app with same package name

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I messed up and accidently lost my key to my app so I have to take down my app and put the new one. Can I keep the same package name or do I need to change it? I unpublished my old app but is there a way to delete it so I can use the same package name?

Thanks!

Comment: you can update or launch new version with same package but can not create another app.

Comment: package name is a Unique name

Answer (score 3):

1 Once you have published your app on google play you can only unpublish it .Deleting the entire app you cannot do it.

2 You cannot create two apps with the same package and upload to play store.

3 Unpublish your current app ...and create a new app with a different package and take care of your keystore :):)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use same package name for more than 1 apps. You can unpublish your app but you can't delete it entirely.